# How to read a 16 bit value from memory

Tags: c, memory, endianness

I have a 4096K binary in memory, in little-endian format. I want to read a couple of the 8 bit values as a `uint16_t` how do I do it in the most performant manner?

```
void execute_cart (i6507_t* cpu, uint8_t* memory) {
    // uint16_t start = memory[0xFFFC]; // this address contains a 16 bit value
}
```

Update: I am running on x86-64 arch, the binary is for an old 8 bit console.

Comment: Is the program running on a little-endian machine, a big-endian machine, or does the same code run on both?

Comment: `uint16_t start = *(uint16_t*)(memory+0xFFFC);` will work on x86.

Comment: @rustyx That invokes undefined behavior by violating C's strict aliasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to read two bytes separately and combine them into a single `uint16_t` variable:

```
unsigned offset = 0xfffc;
uint16_t start = memory[offset];
start |= (uint16_t)memory[offset+1] << 8;
```

**If** `memory` starts an an address that is well aligned and **if** the offset is a multiple of 2, then you can do this in a single read:

```
uint16_t start = *(uint16_t *)&memory[0xfffc];
```

Comment: @sprocket12 that will be system-dependent, but you never answered the question posed to you about your system, so this is portable solution.

Comment: @sprocket12 It can be done, but the memory would need to be properly aligned to do so.  x64 will let you get away with an unaligned read, but not all will.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons a portable solution is good, I guess the faster solution may not work well on ARM.

Comment: `*(uint16_t *)&memory[0xfffc]` does not guarantee a single physical read. It is notionally a single read in the C virtual machine, but it may be implemented with two hardware load instructions. It is not even valid standard C, as it aliases an array of `uint8_t` with `uint16_t`, so the behavior is not defined by the C standard, even if the address is aligned.